# How to create a copy of an embed directory using Golang?

Tags: file, go, embedded-resource

I'm creating a CLI tool and one of the task I'm working on requires to create a new directory and put some files on it. Some files are stored on my source code and embed on the binary using the embed package as

```
//go:embed assets
var assets embed.FS
```

My fs tree looks like this:

```
/
  /assets
    /foo
       foo.txt
       bar.txt
    hello.txt
    goodbye.txt
  main.go
```

So when I run my app I need to copy the content from `assets/foo` into my new generated directory.

I have this so far:

```golang
func copyDir(origin, dirName string) {
    file, err := assets.Open(origin)
    if err != nil {
        internal.CleanUp(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(file)

    dir, err := cfg.FS.ReadDir(origin)
    if err != nil {
        internal.CleanUp(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dir)
}


copyDir("assets/foo", "CopyFoo")
```

The first parameter is the source and the second one is the destination directory on the new generated directory from my CLI.

What I need is a way to copy the content from `assets/foo` into `MyNewDirectory/CopyFoo"

```
Edit
```

I have the following function. It works but its very simple. I wonder if there is a better way to do this:

```golang
func copyDir(cfg *configs.ProjectConfig, origin, dirName string) {
    files, err := cfg.FS.ReadDir(origin)
    if err != nil {
        internal.CleanUp(err)
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", cfg.Name, dirName)); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        os.MkdirAll(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", cfg.Name, dirName), os.ModePerm)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fileContent, err := cfg.FS.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", origin, file.Name()))
        if err != nil {
            internal.CleanUp(err)
        }

        filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%s", cfg.Name, dirName, file.Name())
        f, err := os.Create(filename)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("error os create")
            internal.CleanUp(err)
        }

        if _, err := f.Write(fileContent); err != nil {
            internal.CleanUp(err)
        }

        err = f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            internal.CleanUp(err)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may substitute the `os.Create()`, `f.Write()` and `f.Close()` calls with a single [`os.WriteFile()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#WriteFile) call:

```
for _, file := range files {
    fileContent, err := cfg.FS.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", origin, file.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        internal.CleanUp(err)
    }

    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%s", cfg.Name, dirName, file.Name())
    if err := os.WriteFile(filename, fileContent, 0666); err != nil {
        log.Printf("error os.WriteFile error: %v", err)
        internal.CleanUp(err)
    }
}
```